# Parallelization of queries using multiple Entity Framework contexts

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-6

Consider the situation where I need to perform and combine the results of several isolated queries from the database.  Each individual query is based on a parameter, which is supplied from elsewhere.

One way would be to perform these queries sequentially and union the results:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> GetSomeEntities(List<int> parameters)
{
    var entities = new List<SomeEntity>();

    using(var context = new MyContext())
    {
        entities = parameters.SelectMany(p=> SomeComplexQuery(p);
    }

    return entities;
}
```

The issue with the above solution is that performance is now proportional to the size of the parameter list.  `SomeComplexQuery` is relatively resource-intensive.

Another solution would be to use parallelization:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeEntity> GetSomeEntities(List<int> parameters)
{
    var entities = new List<SomeEntity>();

    Parallel.ForEach(parameters, p => 
    {
        using(var context = new MyContext())
        {
            entities.AddRange(SomeComplexQuery(p)); // Assume thread-safety
        }
    };

    return entities;
}
```

When I run the above solution, I get much better results, but I'm concerned:

- What issues could arise from opening multiple contexts in parallel?  What if we had a parameter list of size 20 or even more?  Could system load result in further undesirable results?
- Specifically for SQL Azure, would this be considered a bad idea due to the added latency when establishing new database connections?

I am using Entity Framework 6, Azure Web Roles and SQL Azure.

Comment: Are you trying to get lots of entities back by using parallelization? If so, perhaps a stored procedure may be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's alright to run multiple threads, each having their own context instance. I'm doing this myself in a process that may give rise to relatively many inserts or updates, so far without any problems.

The .Net connection pool is thread-safe: no physical database connection will suffer from race conditions. The .Net `DbConnection` objects that give access to a physical connection are not thread-safe, but each context manages its own connection objects, so they won't be shared by multiple threads. Sql Azure connections are also pooled, but you'll have to deploy retry strategies (as with any Sql Azure connection). EF6 [supports connection resiliency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456835.aspx).

Note that `List<T>` is not thread-safe. You better use a [concurrent collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `entities`.